# How to change cursor color in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have selected the dracula appearance for pycharm. The background and the mouse cursor both are black. How do I change the mouse cursor color when it is in the code editor tab

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the following menu and you should find it!

```
File
    |
    IDE Settings
        |
        Editor
           |
           Colors & Fonts
               |
               General
                  |
                  Caret Row/Caret
```

It lets you choose the color on the right using a pallet.